# How to know the number of pins on my laptop's ram?

Tags: upgrade

I am thinking about upgrading my laptop's ram.How can I get to know the number of pins on my ram without opening my laptop? I ran this command `sudo dmidecode --type memory` and got following info:

```
Handle 0x0019, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: 0x001A
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: AD00000000000000
    Serial Number: 04008104
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: 040404040404040404040404040404040404
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: "SODIMM", "DDR2" and "667 MHz" is all info you need to know to buy RAM.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this prompt, the key pieces of information to look at are:

- **Location**: DIMM0
- **Size**: 1024MB
- **Form Factor**: SODIMM
- **Type:** DDR2
- **Speed**: 667MHz

The prompt tells you that you have a *SODIMM module* with a *frequency* of *667*MHz occupying the first slot in your motherboard. Since the speed is 667MHz, that likely coincides with the maximum support memory clock frequency for your motherboard.

The # of pins in a DDR2 SODIMM module is 200. For questions like this, I always consult with Google. All you have to do is plug in the relevant information (i.e type, form factor).

**Note:** check how many SODIMM slots are available, and the maximum memory supported by your OS, and motherboard BEFORE you purchase.

**Tip:** If you're using a 32-bit flavour of *nix, you're going to be limited to 4GB of RAM.

Comment: You nay not be limited to 4GB if your kernel supports PAE. as well as your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Ubuntu. But you can go to www.crucial.com and enter your computer information and it will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and Type.

```
sudo lshw

dmidecode -q | less
```

(Last one No need to root access)